# .delay() doesn' t work

Tags: jquery

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo('#due', 800, { margin: true } ).toggleClass('selected'),
    $("body").delay(1000).animate({backgroundColor: "#1c6e7a"},800);   

});
```

The delay function doesn't work in the example. If I remove the .delay value the code works, but I need the background to change AFTER the other function has completed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for it? http://jsfiddle.net/ Thanks!

Comment: @Pointy [ScrollTo | jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: Ah OK, thanks - I figured it was something like that, but in the world of jQuery plugins just knowing the name doesn't always narrow it down to one plugin :-)

Comment: It seems to work just fine [in the fiddle I did.](http://jsfiddle.net/XRpvE/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming this is the [`.scrollTo()`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin.  The plugin allows for a call back after the animation completes.

> onAfter: A function to be called after
>   the whole animation ended.

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo('#due', 800, {
        margin: true,
        onAfter: function () {
            $("body").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#1c6e7a"
            }, 800);
        }
    }).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/K8CKN/2/)**

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so very much! (I did need to remover the comma after 'selected', if anyone else should need this in the future)

Answer (score 0):

I googled about it and i think that backgroundColor cant be animated for that you will need the jQuery plugin color:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs, you can specify a callback with `onAfter`